# Static IBOutlets?

Tags: ios, static, iboutlet

Is there a way to create "Class" outlets?

The idea would be to instantiate those outlets from a Nib only once and share that with all instances.

My main doubt is how to mix

```
@property (...) IBOutlet ...
static ...
@syntetize/@dynamic ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a singleton pattern.

The singleton instance can own your IBOutlets in the normal way and they will be created only once and shared.

Comment: I think that the short answer for truly static outlets is No. But the cleanest approach would be Singletons.

Comment: You are right because there is no concept of class properties. And IBOutlet is a property.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is a good idea, but you can get the effect you are looking for by defining the per-instance setFoo/foo methods to deal with a shared value...

You can declare `@property (...) IBOutlet foo` and define:

```
static id sharedFoo;

-(void)setFoo:(id)newFoo {
    sharedFoo = newFoo;
}

-(id)foo {
    return sharedFoo;
}
```

This might not be a good idea because it isn't all that obvious what you have done, and the old adage of "if you lie to the computer, it will get you" could come into play.

Comment: The problem is that setFoo and foo should be declared with a "+" instead of a "-".

Comment: Are we sure?  It sounded like he wanted to call an instance method to control a "class variable"